# Tracking phone movement Coordinates with accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, motion-detection

I'm new to Android and was playing around with the accelerometer to get data. I am able to get the acceleration values across all 3 axes using the SensorEvent.

Now I was trying to create a small example where I want to track the motion of the phone (in it's own coordinate system). Suppose I touch a point on the screen, I want it to be the (0,0,0) of my system.

Now if I move my screen to the left by 5 cms in a gentle way, I want the screen reading to say my position is (-5,0,0). Same goes for y axis and z axis.

I know that the accelerometer gives only acceleration, but can I use it to determine the position of the phone w.r.t. the original reference point?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.